# Changing cursor on drag in openlayers 3

Tags: openlayers-3

What are the proper way of changing the cursor when user is dragging the map. Below example is not that good as it only triggers when pointerdrag starts the drag and then change it back after no events for 125ms. Is there any other way?

```
    var timer = null;
    this.map().on("pointerdrag",() => {
        this.map().getViewport().style.cursor = "-webkit-grabbing";
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(() => this.map().getViewport().style.cursor = "-webkit-grab", 125); 
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about listening to `pointerup` to reset the cursor?

```
map.getViewport().style.cursor = "-webkit-grab";
map.on('pointerdrag', function(evt) {
    map.getViewport().style.cursor = "-webkit-grabbing";
});

map.on('pointerup', function(evt) {
    map.getViewport().style.cursor = "-webkit-grab";
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9vwgdcyr/